# How to use reg expression with multiple values?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have multiple products on a website and each product has following info:

- ProductId
- ProductName
- ProductPrice

I know how to use it for a single value like `ProductId`, but how should I use it for all the values?

Example: I select product1 from a list and then the other fields should be automatically updated, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter's regular expression extractor stores match groups as JMeter Variables in form of

```
reference name -> underscore -> match number -> underscore -> group number
```

For example, if you have the following Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

- Reference Name: `LINK`
- Regular Expression: `<a href="(.+?)">(.+?)</a>`
- Template: `$1$`

And add it as a Post Processor to i.e. HTTP Request to http://example.com you will receive the following variables:

```
LINKS_1=http://www.iana.org/domains/example
LINKS_1_g=2
LINKS_1_g0=<a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a>
LINKS_1_g1=http://www.iana.org/domains/example
LINKS_1_g2=More information...
```

So you'll be able to access link "href" attribute as `${LINKS_1_g1}` and link text as `${LINKS_1_g2}`

You should be able to use similar approach for your testing.

See [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) guide for more information on the domain.

Comment: Hi Dmitri.Does that mean the first value it will fetch like productid,it will only show relevant data for other fields.

Comment: like we are having following inventory,                                                     pid :101    name:Shampoo   price : $10                                                   pid : 102   name:choc           price:$2                                                       so for pid :101 it will fetch  product name : choc and price $10